# Cross origin issue with Bluemix SSO service

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, single-sign-on

I have a nodeJS express app, that serves front end app using React and also provides an API. The React app calls the backend API and as such there is no cross origin.

When I deploy this to Bluemix without SSO, everything works fine. When I deploy using SSO service I get error

> Fetch API cannot load https://abcd-9bgrvudk1p-ct20.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=Z4eSiL50dT&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole-sso.mybluemix.net%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Fcallback&scope=openid%20openid.
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://console-sso.mybluemix.net' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I tried calling the API directly and after SSO auth, it works fine, But when the API is invoked by the front end app, it returns the above error.

FYI, API target is https://console-sso.mybluemix.net/api/reports/daily-reports

I have followed the [Single Sign On documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/singlesignon_overview.html#singlesignon_overview)

I tried adding CORS module and response headers to allow a CORS request but it did not work. I also tried adding `*` to SSO configuration to allow all origins but no luck. Any pointers would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will require Support to review.  Please open a ticket with the BlueMix support team